express-session / sesssion keeps resetting only on mce site
I am developing a custom app for mce using node.js.
A session is used to store user-specific values.
in app.post('/authCheck') session value is setting, but whenever another request (ex.app.get('/main')) session is newly created. session id is different.
I can't get req.session.value.
The strange thing is , it works fine on localhost.
only on mce site , session is newly created.
I wonder why, can i get some help?
Thank you.

const app = express();
//app.use('/', router);
const ms = new MemoryStore();

const corsOptions = {
  origin : '*',
  credentials : true,
  methods : ["GET", "POST", "PUT"]

};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));

app.use(session({secret : "1234",
    resave : false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store : ms,
    cookie : {
     secure : false
     }
     }));


axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;


app.post('/authCheck', async (req, res) => {
   
    const email = req.body.email;
    const password = req.body.password;
  
    const accounts = await Account.findOne({
        where: { email : email, password : password },
    }); 

   console.log(accounts);
  
   if(accounts !== null){

    req.session.authResult = true;
    req.session.appKey = accounts.dataValues.alimtalk_app_key;
    req.session.secretKey = accounts.dataValues.alimtalk_secret_key;
    req.session.mid = accounts.dataValues.mid;
    req.session.authResult = true;
   
   } else {
    req.session.authResult = false;
   }
   
     res.cookie('appKey', req.session.appKey, {
       sameSite : "none",
       secure : "false"
     });
     
     res.cookie('secretKey', req.session.secretKey, {
       sameSite : "none",
       secure : "false"
     });
     
     console.log(req.session);
     console.log(req.session.id);

    return res.status(200).json({ "authResult" : req.session.authResult, "senderKeys" : req.session.senderKeys, "appKey" : req.session.appKey, "mid" : req.session.mid });

});

app.get('/main', async(req, res) => {
    
    profileInfo = [];
    let senderKeys = [];
    let profileNames = [];

    console.log(req.session.appKey);
    console.log(req.session.secretKey);
    console.log(req.session);

    if(req.cookies){
      req.session.authResult = true;
    } else {
      req.session.authResult = false;
    }
   
    await axios.get(domain + `/alimtalk/v2.3/appkeys/${req.cookies.appKey}/senders`, 
    {
        headers: {
            "contentType" : "application/json",
            "X-Secret-Key" : req.cookies.secretKey,
        }
    })
    .then((res) => {
        
        if(res.data.header.isSuccessful){
            let senders = res.data.senders;
            senders.forEach((sender, index) => {

                if(sender.status === 'YSC03' && sender.kakaoStatus === 'A' && sender.kakaoProfileStatus === 'A'){

                    senderKeys.push(sender.senderKey);
                    profileNames.push(sender.plusFriendId);
                }
            })

            req.session.senderKeys = senderKeys;
            req.session.profileNames = profileNames;
            req.session.authResult = true;
        }
        
    })
    .catch((err) => {

    });
 
 
    if(req.session.authResult){

        for(let i = 0; i < req.session.senderKeys.length; i++ ){
            profileInfo.push({ profileName : req.session.profileNames[i], 
                               senderKey : req.session.senderKeys[i] });
        }

        console.log(profileInfo);
        
    }
    
   
    console.log(req.session.id);
    console.log(req.session.appKey); **==> undefined**
    

    res.render('index', { 
        templates : templates,
        authResult : req.session.authResult,
        profileInfo : profileInfo,
        senderKeys : req.session.senderKeys,

    });
    
})




